# Given a large set 2d points, choose 4 of them to make a polygon with the biggest area

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

[image]

I need an algorithm that will find four points.

These four points form the vertices of a polygon

Which four points make a polygon with the most area?

Sample data: http://jmp.sh/v/8lAytDc00UrOa17Z6Oo6

Comment: Compute the convex hull and try all 4-tuples of its vertices.

Comment: What algorithm can I use to try the remaining values? Convex hull narrows it down, but it is still the same problem, just with less points.

Comment: (Trivial) allegation: the resulting quadrangle doesn't need to be convex (it may have "concave sides"). (Definitely trivial: For every triangle (from the convex hull or otherwise), any fourth point outside will result in a larger area than any from the inside.)

Comment: @greybeard If the convex hull consists of at least 4 points, all points of the quadrangle must lie on the convex hull to maximise the area and therefore, the quadrangle must be convex. If the convex hull has only 3 points, all 3 of them must be part of the quadrangle. Still, that leaves the problem of finding the optimal combination of the points on the convex hull. Perhaps a dynamic programming approach would work?

Comment: @Discretelizard: While a set of five points isn't *large*, consider a triangle with two more points (or a gazillion) within.

Comment: @greybeard My point is that for the case with only 3 points on the convex hull, finding the optimal quadrangle takes only linear time. So this is a degenerate case we can ignore in the rest of the discussion. Of course, a practical algorithm should test for this case.